# Repeated Measures of ANCOVA in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova, ancova

I conducted a study. Here is the structure of the data: https://ibb.co/CzLK9jP
repeated measures (mood_1 and mood_2) dependent variables, group is a between subject factor, and
ruminati is a covariate.

I prepared the data like this in R: https://ibb.co/KWz9GPC However, I do not get the same result from R as I got from SPSS.

It is significant in SPSS, but not significant in R. What is exactly missing here to conduct the same think in the first picture?

```
model <- lm(depression ~ group * ruminati)
anova(model)
```

Comment: Both your image links are broken, but we can't run code on images of data anyway. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ancova_model <- aov(depression ~ group + ruminati, data = data)
```